# LaTexTools in Sublime Text shows only the first line of the error

Tags: sublime-text, latextools

This is an example compilation output I get in Sublime Text:

```
TraditionalBuilder: Engine: xelatex. Invoking texify... done.

Errors:

C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty:121: !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! [\tl_new:N \latinencoding]

[Done!]
```

From what I've understood the "!!!..." is only the first line of the error, and there's no way to see the rest.

Where can I find the exact output log?

Why hasn't this bug been fixed for such a long time? Compilation errors are quite important and not being able to see them is problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sublime writes a `.log` file in the same directory as your `.tex` file which has full output of any warnings/errors, along with other information that might be useful.

The log file is generally quite long, but if you search for `error` or `warning` you can find what you're looking for.